# haskell source compile on Linux

Tags: haskell

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please be patient.

First of all, I don't know anything about Haskell; I program as a hobby with PHP (+HTML/CSS).

#### Situation

A friend of my made a parser to parse freedb textfiles to MySQL in Haskell. He made this for Windows, but now I want to compile the source to a Linux executable on Linux Mint 18.3 64bit. My friend has given me an edit to the source just before he got sick to adjust it to Linux and changed Posix from Windows

```
System.FilePath.Posix (addTrailingPathSeparator,splitFileName,splitPath,takeDirectory)
```

This source compiles very well on Linux and I get a working executable, but the problem comes when I try to run it – this error comes up:

> FreeDb: .\data/ getDirectoryContents: does not exist (no such file or
>   directory)

It should have find a data directory in the directory where the executable is started but obviously .\data/ doesn't work on linux.

Full source:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import HulpFunc
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Text.Parsec.ByteString
import Text.Parsec
import Data.Int
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative((*>),(<*))
import Text.Parsec.Prim((<|>))
import Data.String.Utils (strip)
import Data.Char
import System.FilePath.Posix (addTrailingPathSeparator,splitFileName,splitPath,takeDirectory)
import Control.Monad (filterM,liftM)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents,doesFileExist,doesDirectoryExist)
import System.IO (IOMode(..),hClose,hPrint,hSetEncoding,openFile,latin1,hSetBuffering,BufferMode,hPutStrLn,hGetContents)
import System.Environment
import Data.Time
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Monad
import qualified Control.Concurrent.ThreadManager as TM
import System.Exit (exitFailure)

data Track = Track {
                    t_idx :: !Int,
                    t_title:: !B.ByteString,
                    t_artist:: !B.ByteString,
                    t_offset :: !Int,
                    t_lengthSec :: !Int  -- lengte < 0 => onbekend
                  }  deriving Show

data CD = CD {
            d_id :: !B.ByteString,
            d_title :: !B.ByteString,
            d_artist :: !B.ByteString,
            d_genre :: !B.ByteString,
            d_year :: !Int,
            d_lengthSec :: !Int,
            d_tracks :: ![Track]
          } deriving Show

emptyCD :: CD
emptyCD = CD {
            d_id = "",
            d_title = "",
            d_artist = "",
            d_genre = "",
            d_year = 0,
            d_tracks = [],
            d_lengthSec = 0
          }

freeDbFiles :: String -> IO [String]
freeDbFiles startDir  = do
                            let startDir' = addTrailingPathSeparator startDir
                            names <- getDirectoryContents startDir'
                            let names' = Prelude.filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) names
                                qualifiedNames = map (startDir' ++) names'
                            dirs <-  filterM (doesDirectoryExist . addTrailingPathSeparator) qualifiedNames
                            files <- filterM doesFileExist qualifiedNames
                            subDirFiles <- mapM freeDbFiles dirs
                            return $ files ++ (concat subDirFiles)

insertCmd :: B.ByteString
insertCmd = "INSERT INTO `CDs`\n(`discId`,`genre`,`artiest`,`titel`,`jaar`,`lengte`,`nummers`)\nVALUES\n";

tracksToSQL :: [Track] -> B.ByteString
tracksToSQL  tracks  = surround "\'"  $ foldr (\track str ->
                                                let fieldValueList = map (\f -> (sqlEscape . f) track) [t_artist, t_title, B.pack . show . t_lengthSec]  --list of Bytestrings
                                                    newStr = B.intercalate "@" fieldValueList
                                                in newStr `B.append` "\n" `B.append` str ) "" tracks
showCD :: CD -> B.ByteString
showCD cd = let sqlTracks = tracksToSQL (d_tracks cd)
                cdPart = (B.intercalate ", " $ map (\f -> (sqlField . f) cd)[d_id, d_genre, d_artist, d_title, B.pack . show . d_year, B.pack . show . d_lengthSec])
            in  zetHaakjes (cdPart `B.append` ",\n" `B.append` sqlTracks)

mySpace = (char ' ') <|> tab -- satisfy  (\c -> (c == ' ' ||  c == '\t'))
mySpaces = many mySpace

-- alle parsers voor # (commentlines)
parseToNewLine :: GenParser Char CD B.ByteString
parseToNewLine = do
                    line <- manyTill anyChar eol
                    return $ "parseToNewLine: " `B.append` (B.pack line)

commentLine =   do
                     char '#'
                     mySpaces
                     line <- (try trackFrameOffsets <|> try discLength <|> parseToNewLine)
                     return line

discLength :: GenParser Char CD B.ByteString
discLength  =   do
                    string "Disc length:"
                    mySpaces
                    str <- many digit
                    -- soms staat hier seconds soms niks
                    parseToNewLine
                    updateState (\cd -> cd{d_lengthSec = (read str::Int)})
                    return $ "DiscLength: " `B.append` (B.pack str)

readTrackOffSet=  do
                    char '#'
                    mySpaces
                    str <- many1 digit
                    mySpaces
                    eol
                    return (read str::Int)

trackFrameOffsets = do
                        string "Track frame offsets:"
                        mySpaces
                        eol
                        offSets <- many (try readTrackOffSet)
                        cd <- getState
                        let tracks = map (\(idx,offSet) -> Track { t_idx = idx
                                                                        ,t_title=""
                                                                        ,t_artist=""
                                                                        ,t_offset=offSet
                                                                        ,t_lengthSec = 0
                                                                    }) (zip [0..] offSets)
                            cd' = cd {d_tracks= tracks}
                        updateState (\cd -> cd')
                        return $ B.pack $ "Tracks: " ++ (show $ length offSets)
-- einde # (comment) parsers

eol = do 
        try  (string "\n\r")
        <|> try (string "\r\n")
        <|> string "\n"
        <|> string "\r"

play p s = runParser p emptyCD "parameter" $ B.pack s  -- testen van een parser
playFile p fn = do
                    putStrLn fn
                    hIn <- openFile fn ReadMode
                    hSetEncoding hIn latin1
                    cont <- B.hGetContents hIn
                    B.putStrLn $ B.take 20 cont
                    cont `seq` hClose hIn
                    let res = play p $ B.unpack cont
                    res `seq` (putStrLn $ show res)

testCalcTrackLength =let    cd = CD {d_id = "0c002502", d_title = "Well Well Well", d_artist = "Well Well Well", d_genre = "", d_year = 0, d_tracks = [Track {t_idx = 1, t_title = "Well Well Well2", t_artist = "", t_offset = 150, t_lengthSec = 0},Track {t_idx = 2, t_title = "", t_artist = "", t_offset = 1487, t_lengthSec = 0}], d_lengthSec = 39}
                            sortedTracks = sortBy (\tr1 tr2 -> compOffsets tr1 tr2) (d_tracks cd) -- omgekeerde volgorde
                            combinedTracks = zip sortedTracks (tail sortedTracks)
                            tracksWithLengthNoLastTrack =  map (\(tHi,tLo) -> tLo {t_lengthSec = ((t_offset tHi) - (t_offset tLo)) `div` 75}) combinedTracks
                            lt = head sortedTracks
                            lt' = lt {t_lengthSec = (75 * (d_lengthSec cd) -  (t_offset lt)) `div` 75}
                            tracksWithLength = lt' : tracksWithLengthNoLastTrack
                            cd' = calculateTrackLengths cd
                        in (show tracksWithLength) ++ "\r" ++ (show (tracksToSQL   tracksWithLength))

-- begin keyValue parsers (zonder # aan het begin van de regel)
readIs = do
            mySpaces
            char '='
            mySpaces
            return ""

noHash = notFollowedBy (char '#')

updateTrackInfo :: Int -> B.ByteString ->  B.ByteString -> [Track] -> [Track]
updateTrackInfo idx artist title tracks = map   (\t -> if (t_idx t == idx) then
                                                            t { t_title=title,t_artist=artist}
                                                        else
                                                            t
                                                ) tracks

trackTitle :: GenParser Char CD B.ByteString
trackTitle = do -- dit is alleen voor tracks
                string "TTITLE"
                idxStr <- many1 digit
                readIs
                (fi,la)<- splitLine
                let idx = read idxStr :: Int
                    (art,ti)= if (la == "") then  -- alleen een titel, de artiest komt van de D_TITLE
                                    ("",fi)
                                 else
                                    (fi,la) -- een regel als "de artiest / de titel\n"
                updateState (\cd -> cd {d_tracks = updateTrackInfo idx  art ti (d_tracks cd)})
                return ("TrackIdx: " `B.append` ((B.pack . show) idx) `B.append` ", Art: " `B.append` art `B.append` ", Titel: " `B.append` ti)

-- splits line in left,right by ' / '. Als er geen zit dan alles in left
charNotEol  :: GenParser Char CD Char
charNotEol =  do
                c <-  notFollowedBy eol *> anyChar
                return c

splittableLine :: GenParser Char CD (B.ByteString,B.ByteString)
splittableLine = do
                    le <- manyTill charNotEol (try (string " / "))
                    ri <- restLine
                    return (B.pack le, ri)

noSplittableLine :: GenParser Char CD (B.ByteString,B.ByteString)
noSplittableLine = do
                      s <- restLine
                      return (s,"")

splitLine  :: GenParser Char CD (B.ByteString,B.ByteString)
splitLine = (try splittableLine) <|> noSplittableLine

restEXTD = do  -- extended value voor een disk. Meer EXTDs worden als strings aan elkaar geplakt.
               char 'D'
               readIs
               extd <- restLine
               return extd

restEXTTN = do
               char 'T';
               str <- many digit
               let idx = read str :: Int
               readIs
               value <- restLine
               return value

restLine =    do
                mySpaces
                rest <- (manyTill anyChar eol)
                return $ B.pack rest


restDTitle :: GenParser Char CD B.ByteString
restDTitle =  do
                string "TITLE"
                readIs
                (art,ti) <- splitLine
                updateState( \cd -> cd{d_artist=art,d_title= ti})
                return $ "DTitle: " `B.append` ti `B.append` ", DArtist: " `B.append` art

restDYear :: GenParser Char CD  B.ByteString
restDYear = do
               string "YEAR"
               readIs
               yearStr <- restLine
               let y = if (trim yearStr == "") then
                            0
                       else
                            ((read.B.unpack) yearStr)::Int
               updateState( \cd -> cd{d_year=y})
               return  $ "DYEAR: " `B.append` yearStr

restDGenre :: GenParser Char CD B.ByteString
restDGenre= do
                string "GENRE"
                readIs
                genre <- restLine
                updateState( \cd -> cd{d_genre = genre})
                return genre

restDiscId = do
                string "ISCID"
                readIs
                discId <- restLine
                updateState( \cd -> cd{d_id = discId})
                return discId

dKeyValue = (char 'D') *> choice [restDTitle,restDYear,restDGenre,restDiscId]

keyValue =   do
                noHash
                mySpaces
                res <- choice [dKeyValue,trackTitle,garbageKeyValue]
                return res

garbageKeyValue = do
                    key <- (manyTill anyChar (char '='))
                    mySpaces
                    val <- restLine
                    return  $ "kvGarbage key: "  `B.append` (B.pack key)  `B.append` ", val: " `B.append` val
-- einde keyValue

validCd :: CD -> Bool
validCd cd = let titleStr = d_title cd `B.append` d_artist cd
                 (valid,invalid) =
                              B.foldr (\c (va,inva) -> if isAlphaNum c then
                                                                (va+1,inva)
                                                          else
                                                                (va,inva+1)) (0,0) titleStr
             in  valid > invalid

--validCd cd = True
parseCD :: GenParser Char CD CD
parseCD = do
                setState emptyCD
                commentInfo <- many commentLine
                keyValues <- many keyValue
                cd <- getState
                let cd' = calculateTrackLengths cd 
                updateState (\cd -> cd')
                return $ cd'

-- | omgekeerd sorteren
compOffsets :: Track -> Track -> Ordering
compOffsets t1 t2 =  let off1 = t_offset t1
                         off2 = t_offset t2
                     in case compare off1 off2 of
                        LT -> GT
                        GT -> LT
                        EQ -> EQ

isValidTrackOffset :: Track -> Bool
isValidTrackOffset t = (t_offset t >= 0)

validDiskLength :: CD -> [Track] -> Bool
validDiskLength cd sortedTracks =   if null sortedTracks then  -- sortedTracks: tracks omgekeerd gesorteerd op trackoffset
                                        False
                                    else 
                                        let lt = head sortedTracks
                                        in   75 * (d_lengthSec cd) > (t_offset lt)  -- is de laatste offset van de disk groter dan de offset van het laatste nummer

calculateTrackLengths :: CD -> CD
calculateTrackLengths inCd =    if (all  isValidTrackOffset (d_tracks inCd)) then                                    

                                    let sortedTracks = sortBy (\tr1 tr2 -> compOffsets tr1 tr2) (d_tracks inCd) -- omgekeerde volgorde sorteren op offsets
                                        resTracks=  if null sortedTracks then
                                                        []
                                                    else               
                                                        if validDiskLength inCd sortedTracks then
                                                            let combinedTracks = zip sortedTracks (tail sortedTracks)
                                                                tracksWithLengthNoLastTrack =  map (\(tHi,tLo) -> tLo {t_lengthSec = ((t_offset tHi) - (t_offset tLo)) `div` 75}) combinedTracks
                                                                lt = head sortedTracks
                                                                lt' = lt {t_lengthSec = (d_lengthSec inCd) -  ((t_offset lt) `div` 75)}
                                                                tracksWithLength = lt' : tracksWithLengthNoLastTrack  -- alle track lengthes zijn ingevuld
                                                            in  tracksWithLength
                                                        else
                                                            sortedTracks -- geen valid disklength
                                    in inCd {d_tracks = reverse resTracks}
                                    --in inCd {d_tracks = sortedTracks}
                                else
                                    inCd  -- niet allemaal geldige trackOffsets

parseCDs :: GenParser Char CD [CD]
parseCDs =  do
               res <- manyTill parseCD eof
               return res

parseFile hOutMVar filesChannel = do
                                    fn <- readChan filesChannel
                                    if (fn == "") then
                                        do
                                            writeChan filesChannel "" -- laatste element. Stop recursion en zet de lege string weer op de channel voor andere threads
                                            return () --klaar
                                    else
                                        do
                                            hIn <- openFile fn ReadMode
                                            hSetEncoding hIn latin1
                                            cont <- B.hGetContents hIn                   --bestand inlezen
                                            let res = runParser parseCDs emptyCD "" cont --bestand parsen
                                            res `seq` hClose hIn                         --handle sluiten
                                            hClose hIn
                                            let (sql,errorMsg,valCds) = case res of -- sql en errorMsg zijn een bytestrings
                                                                                (Left err)  -> ("",B.pack $ show err,[])
                                                                                (Right cds) ->  let validCds = filter validCd cds
                                                                                                    lines = B.intercalate ",\n" ((map showCD validCds))
                                                                                                    lines' =  insertCmd `B.append` lines
                                                                                                in  (lines' `B.append` (B.pack ";\n"),"",validCds)
                                            -- er mag maar een thread tegelijk naar het outputbestand schrijven.
                                            hOut <- takeMVar hOutMVar  -- lock aanvragen
                                            putStrLn fn                -- schrijf filename naar scherm
                                            --putStrLn $ show $ head valCds
                                            if not (B.null errorMsg) then
                                                B.putStrLn errorMsg
                                            else
                                                B.putStr ""
                                            B.hPutStrLn hOut sql       -- output naar file
                                            putMVar hOutMVar hOut      -- lock vrijgeven
                                            parseFile hOutMVar filesChannel -- recurse (next file)

parseFiles hOut fns = do
                            tm <- TM.make
                            excludeWrites <- newEmptyMVar
                            mapM (\_ -> TM.fork tm (parseFile excludeWrites fns)) [1..4]
                            putMVar excludeWrites hOut -- hef de block op voor alle threads
                            TM.waitForAll tm --wacht tot alle forks afgelopen zijn.

getOutPutFileName = ".\\output\\CDs.sql"

main = do
            start <- getCurrentTime
            excludeWrites <- newEmptyMVar
            files <- freeDbFiles ".\\data"
            args<- getArgs
            let outputFn =  if null args then getOutPutFileName else head args
            hOut <- openFile outputFn AppendMode
            hSetEncoding hOut latin1
            filesChan <- newChan
            mapM_ (writeChan filesChan) files 
            writeChan filesChan "" -- lege map = klaar
            parseFiles hOut filesChan
            hClose hOut
            stop <- getCurrentTime
            putStrLn "klaar"
            print $ diffUTCTime stop start
```

It includes a helper source:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module HulpFunc(trim,
                rTrim,
                lTrim,
                splitSubStr,
                removeLastChars,
                splitArr,
                surround,
                zetHaakjes,
                sqlEscape,
                sqlQuote,                
                sqlField)

where           

import Text.Parsec.ByteString(Parser)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Int

snoc :: [a] -> a -> [a]
snoc [] s = [s]
snoc (c:cs) s = c: snoc cs s

splitArr :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitArr _   [] = []
splitArr idx xs = let (fi,rest)=splitAt idx xs
                  in fi : (splitArr idx rest)

splitSubStr :: String -> String -> (String,String)
splitSubStr "" str = (str,"")
splitSubStr subStr str =  let (fi,la) = splitSubStrRecurse "" subStr str
                              trimmed = if fi==str then
                                            fi
                                        else
                                            removeLastChars (length subStr) fi
                          in (trimmed, la)

splitSubStrRecurse :: String -> String -> String -> (String {-first-}, String {-last-})
splitSubStrRecurse foundPrefix subStr "" = ("","")
splitSubStrRecurse foundPrefix subStr str = let le = length subStr
                                                c = head str
                                                newFoundPrefix = let pf = snoc foundPrefix c
                                                                 in if length pf > le then
                                                                        tail pf
                                                                    else
                                                                        pf
                                            in  if newFoundPrefix == subStr then
                                                   ([c],drop 1 str)
                                                else
                                                    let (fi,la) = splitSubStrRecurse newFoundPrefix subStr $ tail str
                                                    in ((c : fi), la)

removeLastChars ::  Int -> String  -> String
removeLastChars le s =  let sLe=length s
                        in if sLe <= le then
                               ""
                           else
                              take (sLe-le) s

zetHaakjes :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString                   
zetHaakjes s =  "(" `B.append` s `B.append` ")"

surround  :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
surround surr s = surr `B.append` (s `B.append` surr)

-- sql

sqlQuote = surround "\'"

sqlEscape :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
sqlEscape "" = ""
sqlEscape s =   let t = sqlEscape $ B.tail s
                in  case (B.head s) of
                        '\'' -> "\\'" `B.append` t
                        '\"' -> "\\\"" `B.append` t
                        '\\' -> "\\\\" `B.append` t
                        c  ->  (B.cons c t)

sqlField = sqlQuote .sqlEscape

lTrim :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
lTrim "" = ""
lTrim cs = if (B.head cs ==' ') then  lTrim $ B.tail cs else  cs

rTrim = (B.reverse . lTrim . B.reverse)

trim :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
trim  = rTrim . lTrim
```

Can someone clear this error, or put me in the right direction?

Comment: 1. The operations in the `System.FilePath` module are platform agnostic - your friend probably should have used that for both Linux and windows instead of the discouraged `.Posix` and other platform-specific modules.  2. Local directory is implicit, so I suspect you can just remove all `.\\\` prefixes to strings (I see two) and see how that works.

Comment: Edit: I use Haskell platform from official Linuxmint repo. 2 cabal packages are needed: MissingH and threadmanager both installed from terminal after cabal update

Comment: @thomas Yess it works! I edited the source and changed the .\\ and removed the Posix module. Only remaining problem is the getOutputFilename path is wrong but i fixed that with replacing \\ with / in the path but i think that's not the right way? Is it better in this case to add the Posix module?

Comment: Instead of an explicit `/` you should use the function `</>` from `System.FilePath`.  For example, `dataFilePath </> "someFile" <.> "pdf"` will give the proper slashes for both windows and *nix.

Comment: @Thomas I forgot to thank you very much!!

Comment: @thomas I tried to implant example about filepath but i keep getting errors about not in scope. can you give a example based on the source code 
 getOutputFilename above? Otherwise it is not a big deal because i can keep this as linux only

Comment: See my answer. Basically, you can delete the selective FilePath import and just import everything via `import System.FilePath` or add `(</>)` to the list of functions imported from that module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a unnecessary platform dependent code.  Use `System.FilePath` instead for the platform independent version.  Also, omit the `.\\` prefix since the local directory is implicit.

For an example of platform independent paths, don't do this:

```
getOutPutFileName = ".\\output\\CDs.sql"
```

Instead modify your import to be either all of the module (`import System.FilePath`) or include more functions `import System.FilePath ((</>), ... and the rest...)`.  Then use these functions:

```
getOutPutFileName = "output" </> "CDs.sql"
```